# How to do a join in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

I have a project I'm working on and I had come changes to make.
We are developing an app like Jira, where you have different boards with tasks.
I had to create a pie chart that displays how many tasks does an user have.
My old version of the code was this:

```
= pie_chart Task.all.group(:assigned_id).count.map { |k,v| [User.find(k).full_name, v] }.to_h
```

and it worked. A senior told me to create a single query for getting name and task count pairs. Till now i have something like this, but it's not working:

```
= pie_chart current_account.organization.Tasks = Task.joins(:assigned_id).where(:full_name)
```

Models:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :activities, dependent: :destroy  
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :activities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch
  has_one_attached :logo
  has_many :accounts
  has_many :boards

class Task < ApplicationRecord

  has_one_attached :file
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "Account", foreign_key: "owner_id"
  belongs_to :assigned, class_name: "Account", foreign_key: "assigned_id"
  has_many :subtasks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :activities, dependent: :destroy

class User < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch

  has_many :accounts, dependent: :destroy
  has_one_attached :avatar
```

Comment: You want to display the count of `current_user`'s assigned tasks, is that right? Did you find anything [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) or [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) requiring clarification? What was it?

Comment: Yes, i want that.. the old method worked, it showed the tasks assigned to the users, but a senior asked me to change it and now i struggle.

Comment: If you're struggling, don't be afraid to ask the senior for a steer - if they're good at their job they should be happy to give some advice :) Otherwise, I think the answers here should crack it regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to start the query with the user model, joining the tasks. Then you need to select the fullname and the count of tasks. Something like this should work:

```
data = User.joins(:tasks).select(:fullname, 'count(tasks.id) AS count')
```

You can then map these to get the desired array of arrays:

```
data.map { |x| [x.email, x.count] }.to_h
# => { "A name" => 163, ...}
```

Or in a one liner:

```
= pie_chart User.joins(:tasks).select(:fullname, 'count(tasks.id) AS count').map { |x| [x.email, x.count] }.to_h
```

Hope this helps - let me know how you get on or if you have any questions :)

Comment: Can't join 'User' to association named 'tasks'; perhaps you misspelled it? This is the error it shows me :/

Comment: What's the association between `User` and `Task` - can you update your question with the model code showing this please @arniii69? If it's a standard `belongs_to` relationship this could work, if not, might need a little tinker :)

Comment: Sure thing :) The problem is your users aren't associated to tasks (while you have the reverse association setup). If you update the user model to add `has_many :tasks, inverse_of: :assigned ` (<< might need to tinker a tiny bit there), the above should work perfectly. Let me know @arniii69!

Comment: they are connected with the accounts table
/ User:       has_many :accounts
/ Account:   has_many :tasks

Comment: Ah - in that case you need to add `has_many :tasks, through: :accounts`. Believe that should crack it @arniii69 :)

Comment: How'd you get on with this @arniii69?